# How add to a picture to previously created word document with poi

Tags: apache-poi

In my project, I'm creating word document (.docx) with apache poi. When the document created, project sending it to approvers via e-mail. I want to add a approver's signature picture to specific place to previously created word document, when the approver is approved the document. But I couldn't figure it out how to do it on previously created word document.

Can I add a picture to previously created word document or do i have to rebuilt it?

**UPDATE**

I tried this code part

```
    FileInputStream docxFile=new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("jboss.server.data.dir")+"/corrolog/TestWS/"+strSO+" Test Workscope "+revision+".docx");
    FileInputStream approverFile=new FileInputStream(approvers);
    XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(docxFile);
    List<XWPFParagraph> xwpfParagraphList = doc.getParagraphs();
    for (XWPFParagraph xwpfParagraph : xwpfParagraphList) {
        for (XWPFRun xwpfRun : xwpfParagraph.getRuns()) {
            String text = xwpfRun.getText(0);
            System.out.println(text);
             if (text == "approved signature" && text.equals("approved signature")) {
                 text.replace("approved signature", "");
                 xwpfRun.setText(text);
                 xwpfRun.addPicture(approverFile, XWPFDocument.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG, "approved", Units.toEMU(130), Units.toEMU(55));
             }
        }

    }
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(System.getProperty("jboss.server.data.dir")+"/corrolog/TestWS/"+strSO+" Test Workscope "+revision+" Approved.docx");  
    doc.write(out);
    out.close();
```

But it doesn't add picture to XWPFRun.

**SOLUTION**

```
String approvers=v2500Service.getApproverSignatures(approver).get(0).getImagePath();
        FileInputStream approverFile=new FileInputStream(approvers);)
        XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(Files.newInputStream(Paths.get(System.getProperty("jboss.server.data.dir")+"/corrolog/TestWS/EV13077-04 Test Workscope Rev0.docx")));
        Iterator<IBodyElement> iter = doc.getBodyElementsIterator();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
           IBodyElement elem = iter.next();
           if (elem instanceof XWPFTable) {
               for(XWPFTableRow rows:((XWPFTable) elem).getRows())
               {
                   for(XWPFTableCell cell:rows.getTableCells())
                   {
                       text=cell.getText();
                       System.out.println(text);
                       if(text.equals("approved signature"))
                       {

                           text.replace("approved signature", "");
                           cell.getParagraphArray(0).removeRun(0);
                           cell.getParagraphArray(0).createRun();
                           cell.getParagraphArray(0).getRuns().get(0).addPicture(approverFile, XWPFDocument.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG, "approved", Units.toEMU(130), Units.toEMU(55));
                       }
                   }
               }
               System.out.println(((XWPFTable) elem).getRow(0).getCell(0).getText());
           } 
        }
```

It was about XWPFParagraph, it has to be iterate XWPFTable.

Comment: What have you tried? What problems do you have? You need to get a [XWPFRun](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFRun.html). Then you use [XWPFRun.addPicture](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFRun.html#addPicture-java.io.InputStream-int-java.lang.String-int-int-).

Comment: @AxelRichter I added the code part that i have tried.

Comment: Do some debugging? Will `xwpfRun.addPicture` even reached? I doubt this because `text == "approved signature" && text.equals("approved signature")` will never be true. If `System.out.println(text);` prints "approved signature", then `text.equals("approved signature")` should be `true` and `xwpfRun.addPicture` should work. But `text == "approved signature"` will never be true as it tests whether two different `String` objects are the same.

Comment: @AxelRichter Ahh, yes my mistake. I forgot to change it with || (or). On the other hand, I added this code before first for loop **System.out.println(xwpfParagraphList.get(0).getRuns().get(0).getText(0));**. So I got this **java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0** . Actually, I'm using borderless table in document, can it be the problem?

Comment: Then either `xwpfParagraphList` is empty - what I doubt - or the first paragraph does not have a text run - what could be possible - or the first text run in first paragraph does not have a text - what also could be possible. What prints `System.out.println(text);`? It should print the texts of all runs in all paragraphs. Is one of this texts "approved signature"?

Comment: @AxelRichter I solved the problem. It was about XWPFParagraph, it has to be XWPFTable. So, I'm adding the solution in my question.